# how to use restler of javascript to get html from webpage

Tags: javascript, restler

I am pretty new to the restler. I want to obtain the html contents from a webpage. Could somebody provide some examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What makes you think you need Restler for this?  What's wrong with `http.get()`?  http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: there's some great examples in the readme file for restler: https://github.com/danwrong/restler/blob/master/README.md#example-usage